# In which region is the dialect word '글페' used?

Tags: dialects

글피 means 3 days after today and 글페 is a dialect of this word.

The Naver dictionary says 글페 is a dialect in the Chungbuk, Pyeongbuk, and Hamgyeong provinces. But the Chungbuk and the Pyeongbuk and Hamgyeong provinces are very far away, so it is not very reasonable.
I guess there may be some other region where 글페 is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the Encyclopedia of Korean Culture.

글페 is also used in Hwanghae Province.

http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0078674

There is also a report from the National Institute of Korean Language that searched where 글페 is used as a dialect. This report listed many cities and counties:

- Jeju: North Jeju
- South Jeolla: Goheung
- North Jeolla: Jeong-eup, Gochang, Wanju, Muju,
- North Gyeongsang: Uljin
- North Chungcheong: Cheongwon, Boeun, Okcheon, Yeongdong, Eumseong,
  Goesan, Jecheon
- Gangwon: Gangneung, Pyeongchang, Samcheok, Jeongseon

https://dialect.korean.go.kr/dialect/upload/board/files/20200424150821-2016%EB%85%84%20%EC%A7%80%EC%97%AD%EC%96%B4%20%EC%A0%95%EB%B3%B4%20%ED%99%9C%EC%9A%A9%20%EC%B2%B4%EA%B3%84%20%EA%B5%AC%EC%B6%95%20%EA%B2%B0%EA%B3%BC%20%EB%B3%B4%EA%B3%A0%EC%84%9C.pdf